# Управление памятью внутри функций

Tags: objective-c

Я использую в своем XCode проекте механизм ARC. Не до конца понимаю: если я создаю внутри функции какую-то переменную со звездочкой, то эта переменная уничтожается после завершения функции?

Пример 1 ( *newItem будет уничтожена по завершению функции? ):

```
NSMenuItem *newItem = [[NSMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]] initWithTitle:@"About"                                                                                action:@selector(aboutDockAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[newItem setTarget:[NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate];
[newItem setTag:1];
[appDockMenu addItem:newItem];
```

Пример 2 (тот же вопрос про переменную *list внутри функции):

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// что-то делаем с массивом *list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не будет. Массив appDockMenu будет удерживать объект newItem.

Comment: И как же тогда поступить, если appDockMenu передается в параметре функции, т.е. функция собственно добавляет в appDockMenu пункты меню.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать? Уничтожить newItem? Зачем? Вы же добавляете его в массив. Не копируете, а добавляете! ARC сам уничтожит этот объект когда надо.

Comment: На самом деле это плохой пример наверно, просто хотел понять как это работает. У меня утечки памяти происходят в приложении. Но все равно не до конца понимаю: я использую эту переменную несколько раз, одну и ту же newItem для разных пунктов меню, и несколько раз добавляю ее при помощи [appDockMenu addItem:newItem]. Получается, что она все-таки копируется? Потому что если бы добавлялась, то по идее появились бы несколько одинаковых пунктов меню? А они разные, т.е. меню работает правильно.

Comment: Нет, это не одна итаже переменная newItem. При каждом вызове вашего метода она (переменная) создается заново. Это всего лишь указатель на область памяти, где располагается созданный объект. В массив appDockMenu добавляются указатели на эту область памяти. Утечки памяти ловите с помощью инструментов.

Comment: Ой, а каких инструментов, не подскажете? :)

Comment: интрументы это и есть название утилит встающих с xcode, оно же profile в меню product

Comment: Как же вы определили утечки памяти, если не не знаете про инструменты?
В Xcode: Product -> Profile -> Leaks

Comment: Я определил через debug navigator, что память используемая приложением постоянно растет (у меня таймер используется, и функции вызываются постоянно в цикле). Спасибо, я определил что у меня нет никаких утечек, а я думал, это и называется утечкой. Буду разбираться как тогда называется то, что у меня происходит :)

Comment: Это не всегда является следствием утечек памяти.